# Utilizar valor de um select com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, select, if

Preciso utilizar o valor de um select em um if, no momento tenho isso:

```
Esse seria o HTML:
    <p>Quantidade de vidas? </p>
    <select>
    <option value="vidas1" id="vidas">Mais 1000</option>
    <option value="vidas2" id="vidas">Mais 5000</option>
    <option value="vidas3" id="vidas">Menos 1000</option>
    </select>

    <p>Importancia ?</p>
    <select>
    <option value="marca1" id="marca">Pouco Importante</option>
    <option value="marca2" id="marca">Importante</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" id="resposta" value="Calcular"/>
    <p>Resultado:<p> <span id="resultado"></span>
```

Tendo isso, eu utilizo o JS para pegar o valor do que foi selecionado no select

```
Esse seria o JS:
window.onload = function(){
var btn = document.getElementById("resposta");
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){

var nomedoCliente = parseFloat(document.getElementById("nmCliente").value)
calcular(nomedoCliente);
},false);
function calcular(a){

var clienteNm = document.getElementById("nmCliente").value
var qtdeVidas = document.getElementById("vidas").value
var importanciaOp = document.getElementById("marca").value

if (qtdeVidas == "vidas1" && importanciaOp == "marca1" ) {
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML="<p> "+clienteNm+", identificamos que você se encontra no nivel 1</p>" 
} 
else {
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML="<p> "+clienteNm+"</p>"
}
```

Porém, não importa o valor que eu coloque selecionado, ele sempre entra no primeiro if onde diz que ele se encontra no nivel1, e não sei o que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa, o id do options, deve estar no select, e não no option.
Assim:

```
<select id="vidas">
    <option value="vidas1">Mais 1000</option>
    <option value="vidas2">Mais 5000</option>
    <option value="vidas3">Menos 1000</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está utilizando `getElementById()`. O método `getElementById()` retorna o elemento que possui o atributo ID com o valor especificado. Porém um ID deve ser exclusivo em uma página. No entanto, se houver mais de um elemento com o ID especificado, o método `getElementById()` vai retornar o primeiro elemento somente. No seu caso retornando apenas `vidas1` que é o primeiro ID que ele encontrou na pagina.

---

Você pode utilizar outro método para obter os valores, como `querySelectorAll()`, ou pode editar o seu código da seguinte maneira.

```
<select id="vidas">
  <option value="vidas1" >Mais 1000</option>
  <option value="vidas2">Mais 5000</option>
  <option value="vidas3">Menos 1000</option>
</select>
```

E na hora de manipular o select você pode fazer dessa forma utilizando o `getElementById()`

```
var e = document.getElementById("vidas");
var strVidas = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```